# xml parsing error at line x. Extra content at the end of the document

Tags: xml, xslt

Really struggling with this. I just copied an existing (and working!) xslt and changed up the content so don't know why I keep getting the message "xml parsing error at line x. Extra Content at the end of the document". All my open/clos tags appear correct and I have a root.
I have tried to remove the last tag, but then the message appears with the earlier /. I have tried adding  other closing tags but all to no avail...Please help!

```
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.abcdefg.report/CR_123_Demographics"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xtt="urn:com.abcdefg/xtt">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes">

        <xsl:template match="/">
            <File  xtt:separator="&#xd;&#xa;"  xtt:severity="warning" xtt:charConversion="true">
                <Header xtt:separator=",">
                    <HeaderItem>10017</HeaderItem>
                    <Processingdate xtt:fixedLength="8" xtt:align = "left">
                        <xsl:value-of select="format-date(current-date(),'[Y0001][M01][D01]')"/>
                    </Processingdate>
                </Header>

                <xsl:for-each select="/wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry">
                    <Record xtt:separator=",">
                        <xtt:required="true" xtt:severity="warning"><xsl:value-of select="wd:Employee_ID"/>
                        <xtt:required="true" xtt:severity="warning"><xsl:value-of select="wd:Language_Code"/>
                        <xtt:required="true" xtt:severity="warning"><xsl:value-of select="wd:First_Name"/>
                        <xtt:required="true" xtt:severity="warning"><xsl:value-of select="wd:Last_Name"/>
                        <xtt:required="true" xtt:severity="warning"><xsl:value-of select="wd:Address_1"/>
                        <xtt:required="true" xtt:severity="warning"><xsl:value-of select="wd:Address_2"/>
                        <xtt:required="true" xtt:severity="warning"><xsl:value-of select="wd:City"/>
                        <xtt:required="true" xtt:severity="warning"><xsl:value-of select="wd:Secondary_Country"/>
                        <xtt:required="true" xtt:severity="warning"><xsl:value-of select="wd:Waiver_Flag"/>
                        <xtt:required="true" xtt:severity="warning"><xsl:value-of select="wd:Work_Phone_Area_Code"/>
                        <xtt:required="true" xtt:severity="warning"><xsl:value-of select="wd:Work_Landline"/>
                        <xtt:required="true" xtt:severity="warning"><xsl:value-of select="wd:Item_Value4"/>
                        <xtt:required="true" xtt:severity="warning"><xsl:value-of select="wd:Item_ID5"/>
                        <xtt:required="true" xtt:severity="warning"><xsl:value-of select="wd:Item_Value5"/>
                        <xtt:required="true" xtt:severity="warning"><xsl:value-of select="wd:Primary_Bank"/>
                        </xtt:required="true">
                    </Record>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </File>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:output>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a whole string of start tags of the form

```
 <xtt:required="true" xtt:severity="warning">
```

with no matching end tags.

Pasting the document into an XML editor like Oxygen makes the problem immediately clear.

I agree it's not a very impressive error message.

Comment: They're not even well-formed start tags.

Comment: Hello. I realised I was missing the wrappers so I updated all the lines to include the start and end tags as : <Gender xtt:required="true" xtt:severity="warning"><xsl:value-of select="wd:Gender"/></Gender>

Comment: If the problem is solved, please tick the check-mark to mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

your xslt is not formated. I think you are using document transformation for Workday integrations. I reformated you code and pasting below

```
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:wd="urn:com.abcdefg.report/CR_123_Demographics"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xtt="urn:com.abcdefg/xtt">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <File xtt:separator="&#xd;&#xa;" xtt:severity="warning" xtt:charConversion="true">
            <Header xtt:separator=",">
                <HeaderItem>10017</HeaderItem>
                <Processingdate xtt:fixedLength="8" xtt:align="left">
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-date(current-date(), '[Y0001][M01][D01]')"/>
                </Processingdate>
            </Header>

            <xsl:for-each select="/wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry">
                <Record xtt:separator=",">

                    <item xtt:required="true" xtt:severity="warning">
                        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Employee_ID"/>
                    </item>
                    <item xtt:required="true" xtt:severity="warning">
                        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Language_Code"/>
                    </item>
                    <item xtt:required="true" xtt:severity="warning">
                        <xsl:value-of select="wd:First_Name"/>
                    </item>
                    <item xtt:required="true" xtt:severity="warning">
                        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Last_Name"/>
                    </item>
                    <item xtt:required="true" xtt:severity="warning">
                        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Address_1"/>
                    </item>
                    <item xtt:required="true" xtt:severity="warning">
                        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Address_2"/>
                    </item>
                    <item xtt:required="true" xtt:severity="warning">
                        <xsl:value-of select="wd:City"/>
                    </item>
                    <item xtt:required="true" xtt:severity="warning">
                        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Secondary_Country"/>
                    </item>
                    <item xtt:required="true" xtt:severity="warning">
                        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Waiver_Flag"/>
                    </item>
                    <item xtt:required="true" xtt:severity="warning">
                        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Work_Phone_Area_Code"/>
                    </item>
                    <item xtt:required="true" xtt:severity="warning">
                        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Work_Landline"/>
                    </item>
                    <item xtt:required="true" xtt:severity="warning">
                        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Item_Value4"/>
                    </item>
                    <item xtt:required="true" xtt:severity="warning">
                        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Item_ID5"/>
                    </item>
                    <item xtt:required="true" xtt:severity="warning">
                        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Item_Value5"/>
                    </item>
                    <item xtt:required="true" xtt:severity="warning">
                        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Primary_Bank"/>
                    </item>

                </Record>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </File>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```